# Transfer data between objects of same structure but different type

Tags: c#

I have two derived classes.

```
public Class A : BaseClass
{
    public static somecomplextype Criteria { get; set; }
}

public Class B : BaseClass
{
    public static somecomplextype Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

I have only access to derived classes and not the base class.

Now I have a another class

```
public Class SomeClass
{
   public SomeClass()
   {
       //I need a logic for the below to happen...
       B.Criteria = (B) A.Criteria //throws invalid cast exception
   }
}
```

The problem is transferring the data between A.Criteria to B.Criteria...

Since the cast throws exception..

I wanted to know if there is another way.

Comment: No, you cannot cast one sub-type of `A` to another sub-type of `B`. You can create a constructor to produce an object of sub-type `A` from object of sub-type `B`, and vice versa, but I can find very few usage cases for such design. Make sure that you know what you do, and ask yourself (or Software Engineering / Programming SE) **why** you decided to do that and is there a better architectural solution?

Comment: What cast? How does casting tie in with your data transfer problem?

Comment: Don't create two identical types if you want instances of them to be treated identically to each other.  Just have one type to begin with.

Comment: there's no special way to do it just because the two classes have a common base.

Comment: the objects are from a wcf service. I don't have control over the structure of those objects. I need to consume the wcf service. I need to get Criteria from A and give it B. but their types are different and but their inline basic structure are same since they are derived from the same base class.

Comment: Maybe you should use extension methods for `A` and `B` classes?
If I understood, you need method like: `A a = new A(); B b = new B(); b.GetCriteriaFromA(a);` ?

Comment: I have edited my question for a better picture.

Comment: Yes. it is intentional. the base objective is to transfer the data contained in `A.Criteria` to `B.Criteria`. The problem I have is the `Criteria` is a big object which also has enum in it's sub constructs which is also of different types. Say I have a sub contruct of type 'enum x { }' then there are two types A.x and B.x which makes it difficult to transfer the data between those. So I am expecting a simpler solution which might not be direct way.

Comment: It sounds like your question boils down to "how can I create an object of one type from an object of a different type?" The answer is that you create a method that knows about the two types and how to create one from the other (these are usually named `Convert`). Then you could do something like `B.find(Convert.ToBCriteria(A.GetCriteriaFromStore));`. For examples you see [The Convert Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have found a roundabout way to transfer data between them. Pasting the code here FWIW                                                                                                                                      
`string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(A.Criteria);
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(B.Criteria)) as B.Criteria;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I specified is rather simple. I just wanted to transfer the data from one derived type object to another derived type object of same base since I don't have access to base class.

Since the object was big, I was required to write a long data transfer logic for the data transfer between them.

So I was looking for a simple solution like a cast(which won't work in my case).

I have found a roundabout way to transfer data between them. Pasting the code here FWIW

if `A.Criteria` and `B.Criteria` are the objects, I wanted data of A to be passed to B. After all the suggestions above. I came up with a round about way.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(A.Criteria);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(B.Criteria)) as B.Criteria;
```